Plotting missing values - python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
import missingno as msno
import warnings # Ignores any warning
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 5
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option ('display.large_repr', 'truncate')
pd.set_option ('display.max_colwidth', 30)

#Here the first rows of the dataset which includes the unwanted headers are removed.
train = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\data analysis\\sales data correct .csv", header = 6)
#If the country is empty such rows are omitted.
unwantedrows = train.dropna (subset = ["Country"], inplace = True)
print (train.head(5))
#to plot 
msno.matrix(train)
plt.show()

I have a large dataset with missing values. To find the pattern of missing values I am trying to visualize them according to the column values.
The dataset contains quality, country and a couple of years. It is about sales occurred during these years.
Manually it can be identified that missing values are because the company has not introduced themselves to those countries in the missing years.
How to find this visually using any python libraries?
What I need is in Y axis the Quality column values (Standard, premium) to be displayed and x axis contains the rest of columns including quality.



Quality
Country
1994
1995
1996




Standard
USA
123
345
789


Standard
UK
NA
45
78


Standard
Europe
NA
NA
56


Premium
USA
56
67
56


Premium
UK
NA
45
24



Sample of what I need
Tried using msno.matrix. But it does not state the column values.
